# Why the TCP/IP server response and client data is not same?

Tags: node.js, server, client, tcp

I am sending a TCP server response generated randomly in every 1 sec. The data received by the client is not same, why?

As you may see the TCP server & client code below along with their respective logs, are not same. The val field is different in both the logs but id and date is correct. Can any one tell me why?

What I have tried till now

1. On server.js randomData() --> Math.random() * 100
2. On server.js randomData() --> parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
3. On server.js randomData() --> " " + parseInt(Math.random() * 100)

none of the above worked. I thought it could be because of

TCP server code -

```
var net = require('net');

// Configuration parameters
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 1337;
var i = 0;
// Create Server instance 
var server = net.createServer((server) => {
    var remoteAddress = server.remoteAddress + ':' + server.remotePort;
    console.log('new client connected: %s', remoteAddress);
    server.on('data', function() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let response = JSON.stringify(randomData(i));
            console.dir(randomData(i), { depth: null, colors: true })
            server.write(response);
            i++;
        }, 1000);

    });
    server.on('close', function() {
        console.log('connection from %s closed', remoteAddress);
    });
    server.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Connection %s error: %s', remoteAddress, err.message);
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('server listening on %j', server.address());
});

function randomData(id) {
    let data = {
        id: id,
        val: " " + parseInt(Math.random() * 100) + " ",
        date: Date()
    }
    return data;
}
```

Server log -

```
node server.js
server listening on {"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":1337}
new client connected: 127.0.0.1:62227
{ id: 0,
  val: ' 96 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 1,
  val: ' 70 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 2,
  val: ' 70 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 3,
  val: ' 74 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 4,
  val: ' 34 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 5,
  val: ' 1 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 6,
  val: ' 86 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 7,
  val: ' 6 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
```

TCP Client code -

```
let net = require('net');
let config = {
    'data': 'mr black',
    'format': 'JSON'
}

let client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write(JSON.stringify(config));
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
   /* console.log(data);
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));*/
    console.dir(JSON.parse(data.toString()), { depth: null, colors: true })
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write(JSON.stringify(config));
    });
});

// client.on('close', function() {
//     console.log('Connection closed');
// });
```

client log -

```
Connected
{ id: 0,
  val: ' 95 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 1,
  val: ' 77 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 2,
  val: ' 67 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 3,
  val: ' 81 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 4,
  val: ' 45 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 5,
  val: ' 2 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 6,
  val: ' 41 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
{ id: 7,
  val: ' 14 ',
  date: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 01:12:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server.js, when you call randomData two separate times you generate two different responses - one you send and the other you log.

```
let response = JSON.stringify(randomData(i));
console.dir(randomData(i), { depth: null, colors: true })
```

Instead of calling randomData twice (which will generate two separate random numbers) you should pass the object `response` to your `console.dir` call.